# Share Java logic between Android and Blackberry projects?

Tags: android, blackberry

Both Android and Blackberry apps are made in Java. Does it mean that I can code some logic interdependent to Android SDK and use it when porting the app to Blackberry?

Does anyone has experience in this field?

Comment: Why negative vote??? There are no articles on this topic on the net.

Comment: +1 I agree. Perfectly legitimate question & I'd be interested in reading the answers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can do it. The logic would not be different but the implementation of the logic depend upon the Platform you are choosing. In Blackberry it uses java-me  but there are some limitation you can not use in Blackberry like there is no ArrayList or HashMap in Blackberry but its available in Android so you have to use some alternative of ArrayList or HashMap while porting for the Blackberry you can use Vector instead of that. There is also some limitation of using java.lang.utils package in Blackberry. May be this would be helpful for you.

Comment: So no ArrayList and HashMap. Thanks. I see that I'd have to look for differences between Java and Java ME

Comment: yeah sure and some limitation of String class too, BlackBerry dont support all the methods for the String class which you can find in android like split(String), and some others too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on an application that runs on both Android and Blackberry. 
I work only on the Android client but I know that only few things can be shared. Of course only the classes that do not have to do with the framework. Another problem is that, Blackberry uses only J2ME that means that for example you can't even use semaphore or other things like that.

In my application all the protocol level is shared though.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Create a plain Java project and make sure you only use classes available in Android and Blackberry. Add the project dependency to your Android and Blackberry project. Alternatively, you can export a jar file and link your projects to it.